# Optionally loading/selecting a column in linq

Tags: c#, linq

So lets say I have a linq query like so

```
var stuff = from t1 in TableOne
            let t2 = t1.TableTwo
            where t1.id = "someId"
            select
            new
               {
                 column1 = t1.Col1,
                 column2 = t2.Col1
                 column3 = (from t3 in TableThree
                            where t3.id = "someId"
                            select new SomeObject
                            {
                                Field1 = t3.Col1,
                                Field2 = t3.Col2
                            }).ToList()
                }
```

Now in some scenarios i want to load the data in column 3, as in when a parameter passed in to the method contains this is not null. And when the parameter is null i dont want to load it for effciencies sake. Any suggestions on how i can achieve the desired result?

Comment: `if (not null) /* what you have */ else ... select new { /* don't select column 3 here */ }` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your subquery check if the parameter `someParameter`  is not null.

```
column3 = (from t3 in TableThree
           where 
              someParameter != null &&
              t3.id == "someId"
           select new SomeObject
           {
                Field1 = t3.Col1,
                Field2 = t3.Col2
           }).ToList()
```

Comment: I love it when the answer is so simple and should have stared me in the face the whole time! thanks!